# Swap values of column of lists that has nans

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension, geopy

[image]I have a data frame with columns:

```html
pd.DataFrame({'col':[[-74.61286283, 40.56889437], [nan, nan], [-105.18943020000002, 40.07872419], [-96.83537306, 32.82099448]]})
```

This column is a longitude-latitude column, but I want to make it latitude-longitude. and swap their positions, so that I can use this along with another similar column to calculate distance using geopy.
I tried this:

```html
df['col'].apply(lambda x: [x[1], x[0]])
```

But it is giving me error:
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
I understand this is because of nan values, I also tried to replace nan with 0, but no luck. Then it gives error:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
Please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure about your iinput ? because `df['col'].apply(lambda x: [x[1], x[0]])` is working for me

Comment: I think there's something in your real data that is causing this problem, not the data you have posted.

Comment: now it says IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Perhaps you would like to share a picture of your real data?

Comment: I have added a screenshot. I have tried to replace 0 with 0, 0 but not happening

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use list comprehension to do the work since it's just switching between the values in the list.

```
df['new'] = [[lat,long] for long, lat in df['col']]

df
Out[15]: 
                                  col                                 new
0         [-74.61286283, 40.56889437]         [40.56889437, -74.61286283]
1                          [nan, nan]                          [nan, nan]
2  [-105.18943020000002, 40.07872419]  [40.07872419, -105.18943020000002]
3         [-96.83537306, 32.82099448]         [32.82099448, -96.83537306]
```

### Update

Since your data has a list `[0]`, it will cause trouble while doing the list comprehension above. If you do not want to drop it. You can do it this way to make it equal length with other rows.

```
df['col'].loc[df['col'].isin([[0]])] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x + [0])
```